# spring cloud gateway throws Load balancer does not have available server for client

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Eureka + Gateway + BackendServerA + BackendServerB. After BackendServerB is down, it throws exception:

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: service-B
```

Event after I manually reboot serverB, it still throws the same error with a 500 http code returned. However, if I turn on the other 3 servers before Gateway, it works properly. I used `application.properties` file to configure routes.

Comment: This is a known issue, but I didn't have a github issue for it. Created https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/236

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks. I was about to test if services could be turned on at a random sequence, before which I found this CGW "cannot recover from  lost-and-found" issue. Do you have a timetable for its fix?

Comment: Probably tomorrow

Comment: @spencergibb >.< nice! And do you have a plan to support multiple instances and master-slave schema? It would be nice to have a throttle among multiple GW. Now I am writing a token bucket, that stores tokens in a cache server, And because of GWs are on different docker, they cannot achieve submillisecond's time synchronization, one of them would be in charge of token refill (master) other GWs would take tokens out. In this way, for a fully autonomous MS system, it needs master election.

Comment: gateway is stateless, you can have multiple gateways running. I have no plans for a primary->secondary system.